# Getting 404 status error in cachedNetworkImage crashing APP

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using CacheNetworkImage in flutter for fetching images from S3 bucket but if it is not able to find image it returns status code 404 
with the exception that crashes the app. I want to ask how to handle this behavior.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
imageUrl: this.coverImage,
fit: BoxFit.fill,
errorWidget: (context, url, error) => 
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
image: AssetImage(
'assets/images/event- 
placeholder.png'),
fit: BoxFit.fill),
borderRadius:
BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),),
),

    [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: HttpException: No valid statuscode. Statuscode was 404
    #0      BaseCacheManager.getFile 
    package:flutter_cache_manager/src/cache_manager.dart:120
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      CachedNetworkImageState._animatedWidget 
    package:cached_network_image/src/cached_image_widget.dart:270
    #2      CachedNetworkImageState.build 
    package:cached_network_image/src/cached_image_widget.dart:196
    #3      StatefulElement.build 
    package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4012
    #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
    package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
    #5      Element.rebuild 
    package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3721
    #6      BuildOwner.buildScope 
    package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2340
    #7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame 
    package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:700
    #8      _Widge<…>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom cache manager from `flutter_cache_manager` package and pass a instance of it to the `CachedNetworkImage.cacheManager`

example:

```
class DefaultCacheManagerWithHandler extends DefaultCacheManager {

  @override
  Stream<FileInfo> getFile(String url, {Map<String, String> headers}) async* {
    var stream = super.getFile(url, headers: headers);
    try {
      await for (var value in stream) {
        yield value
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield null;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Stream<FileInfo> getFile(String url, {Map<String, String> headers}) async* {
    var cacheFile = await getFileFromCache(url);
    if (cacheFile != null) {
      yield cacheFile;
    }
    if (cacheFile == null || cacheFile.validTill.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      try {
        var webFile = await webHelper.downloadFile(url, authHeaders: headers);
        if (webFile != null) {
          yield webFile;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        if (cacheFile == null) {
          throw e;
        }
      }
    }
  }
This is the code of flutter cache manager

Comment: correct me if i am wrong if i make modification in flutter  cache_manager.dart then CacheNetworkImage will itself work.is it a good peactice?

Comment: @kunaljosh369 you should not change the library itself because everytime you do a flutter pub upgrade ( sometimes flutter pub get too ) it deletes all your changes. also it doesn't track your edits in the version control

Comment: I think you have to implement instead of extends.it is not getting extended